# Google spreadsheet : check if similar value and then copy row

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, similarity

I have two columns containing names (A and B) and a third one with positions (C). At the moment C positions are matching B column. I want C positions to match A column in column D.

| A | B | C | D (expected values) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Apples | Fridge | Fridge |
| Oranges | Bananas | Kitchen | Fridge |
|  | Oranges | Fridge |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A; B1:C; 2; 0)))
```

[image]